# Is it possible to use class as a directive attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, I have a directive:

```
<my-button class="btn"></my-button>
```

Then in my directive:

```
angular.directive('myButton', function() {
    return {
        template: '<button class="{{ class }}"> </button>',
        scope: {
            class: "@"
        }
    } 
}
```

What's happening here is that the class is also applied on my-button instead of on button only. Is there a way for me to 'disable' the default features of class? I'd really like to use class instead of, for example, my-button-class.

Thanks!

Comment: You can get attributes through the link function: `link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { var myClass = attrs.class; }`

Comment: use a different attribute than `class`

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ds5pq8nm/3/

Answer (score 0):

add replace true in directive.

dont need to write class={{class}}

its auto copy class

Comment: But some sources say replace is very buggy option.